# How to write content of a list into an Excel sheet using openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I have the following list:

```
d_list = ["No., Start Name, Destination, Distance (miles)",
"1,ALBANY,NY CRAFT,28",
"2,GRACO,PIONEER,39",
"3,FONDA,ROME,41",
"4,NICCE,MARRINERS,132",
"5,TOUCAN,SUBVERSIVE,100",
"6,POLL,CONVERGENCE,28",
"7,STONE HOUSE,HUDSON VALLEY,9",
"8,GLOUCESTER GRAIN,BLACK MUDD POND,75",
"9,ARMY LEAGUE,MUMURA,190",
"10,MURRAY,FARMINGDALE,123"]
```

So, basically, the list consists of thousands of elements (just showed here a sample of 10), each is a string of comma separated elements. I'd like to write this into a new worksheet in a workbook.

**Note: the workbook already exists and contains other sheets, I'm just adding a new sheet with this data.**

My code:

```
    import openpyxl
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('data.xlsx')
    sheet = wb.create_sheet(title='distance')
    for i in range(len(d_list)):
        sheet.append(list(d_list[i]))
```

I'm expecting (in this example) 11 rows of data, each with 4 columns.  However, I'm getting 11 rows alright but with each character of each string written in each cell! I think am almost there ... what am I missing? (Note: I've read through all the available posts related to this topic, but couldn't find any that answers this specific type of of question, hence I'm asking).

Many thanks!

Comment: How wide do you want your rows to be? In openpyxl you can just append a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [pandas](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_pandas) to solve this:

1.) Convert your list into a dataframe:

```
In [231]: l
Out[231]: 
['No., Start Name, Destination, Distance (miles)',
 '1,ALBANY,NY CRAFT,28',
 '2,GRACO,PIONEER,39',
 '3,FONDA,ROME,41',
 '4,NICCE,MARRINERS,132',
 '5,TOUCAN,SUBVERSIVE,100',
 '6,POLL,CONVERGENCE,28',
 '7,STONE HOUSE,HUDSON VALLEY,9',
 '8,GLOUCESTER GRAIN,BLACK MUDD POND,75',
 '9,ARMY LEAGUE,MUMURA,190',
 '10,MURRAY,FARMINGDALE,123']

In [228]: df = pd.DataFrame([i.split(",") for i in l])

In [229]: df
Out[229]: 
      0                 1                2                  3
0   No.        Start Name      Destination   Distance (miles)
1     1            ALBANY         NY CRAFT                 28
2     2             GRACO          PIONEER                 39
3     3             FONDA             ROME                 41
4     4             NICCE        MARRINERS                132
5     5            TOUCAN       SUBVERSIVE                100
6     6              POLL      CONVERGENCE                 28
7     7       STONE HOUSE    HUDSON VALLEY                  9
8     8  GLOUCESTER GRAIN  BLACK MUDD POND                 75
9     9       ARMY LEAGUE           MUMURA                190
10   10            MURRAY      FARMINGDALE                123
```

2.) Write the above Dataframe to excel in a new-sheet in 4 columns:

```
import numpy as np
from openpyxl import load_workbook

path = "data.xlsx"

book = load_workbook(path)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine = 'openpyxl')
writer.book = book

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'distance')
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Comment: No need to use Pandsa here at all. The list can be broken down and added directly in Pandas.

Comment: @CharlieClark I don't see any issue using Pandas here. Just another way. It does help you avoid loops.

Comment: No it doesn't you have as many loop, perhaps even more, here as doing it directly. You also have the overhead of going to a dataframe and back.

Comment: Wow, this is interesting!  i will now take some time to learn about Pandas ... is it a package/method of data manipulation? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I'm back to say thank you immensely!  this works, really appreciate the help!

Comment: Hi again! I'm having a small but very annoying problem I hope you could help me with: the workbook (data.xlsx) am trying to write this data to already contains other sheets, and I need to add the new sheet "distance" to that workbook. The end result is that all the other sheets are being wiped out, and only the 'distance' sheet is left in the workbook. I tried any number of things, to no avail. How to write this data in a new 'distance' sheet and add it to the other sheets in the 'data.xlsx' workbook? thx.